# module_eval and namespace scoping

Tags: ruby

I am trying to build an api that uses different versions of classes in different contexts.  Why does the following code return a uninitialized constant Project error rather than look up the correct constant in the module?

```
module A
  module B
    class Project
    end
  end
end

A::B.module_eval do
  puts Project
end
```

end

Comment: this does seem to be strange. notably `A::B.module_eval "Project"` is fine

Comment: It only happens with the block form, the string argument form works fine `A::B.module_eval "puts Project"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a block in `module_eval`, [it doesn't change the way constants are looked up in the block](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/131801). It only changes the lookup for methods, instance and class variables. This is due to the necessary effects of the block being a closure, and keeping some of it's own surrounding environment.

This can be worked around by either using the string version of `module_eval` or manually looking up the constant via const_get:

```
module A
  module B
    class Project
    end
  end
end

A::B.module_eval{ const_get(:Project) }
  #=> A::B::Project
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I wondered if it was something to do with the closure too, very helpful +1.